# Is it possible to max out both health and stamina?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In Breath of the Wild, there were only enough Spirit Orbs to obtain max health or max stamina, but you couldn't max out both (without using buffs that is). During the intro sequence of Tears of the Kingdom, Link was maxed out in both health and stamina.

If I were to do every shrine, would it possible to max out health *and* stamina? Or is it an either/or like Breath of the Wild?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need 37 more Heart containers (capped at 40) and 2 more Stamina wheels which are upgraded by 1/5 each time (capped at 3 wheels). So 37 + 10 makes a total of **47 upgrades needed**.

There are 152 shrines, and giving that

> you need to exchange 4 *Light of Blessings* at the *Goddess Statues* to get one Heart Container or Stamina Vessel

you can receive 38 upgrades with this method.

As far as I know, 7 additional Heart containers are given

> through dungeons or by defeating certain bosses/challenges.

This makes a grand total of **44 available upgrades**.

So the answer is NO, you should end short by 2 upgrades...

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I may be wrong, haven't reached end game yet.</sub>

Comment: At the risk of compounding a math error -- in your "27 + 20", wouldn't you only need 10 upgrades? (5 upgrades per wheel, max 2 wheels = 10, not 20) So your actual number is 37 upgrades needed?

Comment: @RavenDreamer monday, apparently I can't even do basic math...

Comment: So what happens with the additional 7 upgrades?

Comment: Do you have a source for 30 being the number for max hearts? I thought it was 40 in this game?

Comment: @scohe001 that explains my "bad math" in my original answer, which was in fact correct. 47 needed upgrades and 44 available, so it's not possible to max both. Reddit kinda confirms it's 40.

Comment: There is actually one un-accounted-for heart container, bringing the total missing count to 2.

Comment: @Seiyria feel free to edit the answer if you want